# how to do similar routing like with react-router

Tags: typescript, remix.run

I have set up this routing right now in my SPA app

```
export const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    index: true,
    element: <Landing />,
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <FormLayout />,
    children: [/* ... */],
  },
  { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/" /> },
];
```

how to achieve the same result with remix file structure routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you have a Landing component which is a layout (so I suppose you render an Outlet?) and a FormLayout which is rendered inside the Landing layout when the user is at `/`, then for any other route you redirect to `/`, that's correct?

Supposing that's correct you would have to do it like this:

```
routes/__landing.tsx
routes/__landing/index.tsx
routes/$.tsx
```

That `routes/__landing.tsx` thing is called a [Pathless Layout Route](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#pathless-layout-routes) which is a layout route that doesn't add segments to the URL, so the final URL is going to be `/` and not `/__landing`. Inside this file you should render an `<Outlet />` where the nested routes will be rendered.

The `/routes/__landing/index.tsx` is a nested route inside the `routes/__landing.tsx`, the component of this route it's going to be rendered where the parent placed the `<Outlet />`. All `index` files match the URLs `/`.

The `routes/$.tsx` is a [splat route](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#splat-routes) (or catch-all route) which will match every other URL, there you can put a redirect like this:

```
import type { LoaderFunction } from "remix";
import { redirect } from "remix";

export loader: LoaderFunction = async () => {
  return redirect("/");
}
```

But I recommend you to don't redirect all routes to `/` and instead render a not found page with the correct 404 status code. You can put the error pages inside the `root.tsx` file [CatchBoundary](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#catchboundary) or [ErrorBoundary](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#errorboundary) exports.